# Apply Sorting On DataTable with where clause

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, data-binding, datatable

I have a `DataTable`. and i want to apply sorting on a column using C# Sort function.
But i want sort only apply those row which a specific value into other column(not a column on which sorting is applyed) but table data not filtered.
How can i do this thing.

For Example -  My `DataTable` `dt`

> Column First  (Entity)   ||   Column Second (Location)
>
> Candidate                 ||   0
>
> Employee                                  ||   india
>
> Candidate                                  ||   2
>
> Employee                                   ||   england
>
> Candidate                               ||   3
>
> Employee                                 ||   china

After applying sorting i want my `DataTable` look like this (Sorting apply only those field which only have "Employee" into first column and after sorting both "Candidate" or sorted "Employee" show in `Datatable`)

My expected result after sorting look like this -

> Column First  (Entity)   ||   Column Second (Location)
>
> Candidate                 ||   0
>
> Employee                                 ||   china
>
> Candidate                                  ||   2
>
> Employee                                   ||   england
>
> Candidate                               ||   3
>
> Employee                                  ||   india

thanks a bunch for your valuable help.

Comment: What exactly is the functionality you're trying to achieve here? Based on that, maybe a design change in the data table will be a lot more helpful.

Comment: I want this becoz my second column of datatable have two type of value , mean for employee second column have "employee location" and in case of Candidate my second column have "Performance Rating". so i want when i apply sort according "Location" my data was sort according to Employee-location not Performance-Rating . But here i have same column for both candidate or employee, i can not apply sort directly on "column second" becoz it give incorrect result. So when apply sort according "Location" it's apply only for employee  record and candidate record  does not effected by this. Thank you

Comment: This actually calls for two data tables - The first one having columns Candidate, Rating. The second one should have columns Employee, Location. You could then do your operations more flexibly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use DataView for that, DataView is sortable.Assign your Datatable dt to DataView and use the Sort property of DataView

```
DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
dv.Sort = "Column name";
```

Hope it helps for you.